# I've been trying to use Pycharm but when I create a project using venv it just doesn't detect the pythong installed. What do I do?

Tags: python, 22.04, python3, pycharm

I don't exactly know what's the problem but it just doesn't detect the python installed on my system whether it is the pre-packaged with Ubuntu or a manually installed one.
About two months ago I was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa and it didn't have this problem. Then I switched to kubuntu Jammy Jellyfish, and this problem was there too. Then due to some unfortunate events my whole OS got corrupted so I had to install the system again and this time I changed back to GNOME but Jammy Jellyfish. And this problem is here too.
I get this screen when I try to create a new project=>
[Pycharm Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag2rg.png)
So what do I do?